# CMS Actions in Spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

We are planning to migrate existing storefront to Spartacus.

Does Spartacus support CMS Actions like AddToCartAction which was previously used in the JSP based storefront. If so can anyone please let me known any OOTB component action implementation done in Spartacus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, there is no support for CMS Actions in Spartacus.